# How to download cookbooks from supermarked with deps?

Tags: rsa, chef-infra, knife

I need to download some cookbooks. They have a lot of dependencies. I've machine with knife & chef installed. I want just to download public cookbooks.

When i execute `knife cookbook download git` i get following error:
ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from /home/vagrant/.chef/vagrant.pem
Check your configuration file and ensure that your private key is readable

knife configure initial does not help - it does not generate any keys. So, why do i need any keys & how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `knife cookbook download` will attempt to download cookbook from your Chef server (or from the one you have configured in your `knife.rb`, and so you need the credentials to do that). To download a cookbook from Chef supermarket you must use `knife cookbook site` command, so for example you should use `knife cookbook site download git`. Anyway this won't download the cookbook dependencies, if any.

To manage all your cookbook dependencies, download and/or generate a package with all them, or configure it in a more configurable way, you should take a look to [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/). It's included in ChefDK and you can use to generate a package with all your dependencies, or used in your workstation to upload the required cookbooks with all the dependencies, manage cookbooks versions, different locations,...